# Does Tensorflow support Tesla K80

Tags: cuda, tensorflow

I'm running Tensorflow 0.8 on Tesla K80 with CUDA 7.5 and CUDNN v5. Everything is fine but two devices can't access each other.

The warning log is listed below. Thank you.

```
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:59] cannot enable peer access from device ordinal 0 to device ordinal 2
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:59] cannot enable peer access from device ordinal 0 to device ordinal 3
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:59] cannot enable peer access from device ordinal 1 to device ordinal 2
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:59] cannot enable peer access from device ordinal 1 to device ordinal 3
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:59] cannot enable peer access from device ordinal 2 to device ordinal 0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:59] cannot enable peer access from device ordinal 2 to device ordinal 1
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:59] cannot enable peer access from device ordinal 3 to device ordinal 0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:59] cannot enable peer access from device ordinal 3 to device ordinal 1
```

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use Tensorflow on K80's.  The warnings you are showing are a result of the configuration of the system that the K80's are plugged into, and not specific to the K80 GPU or Tensorflow.  NVIDIA provides sample codes (e.g. simpleP2P, p2pBandwidthLatencyTest, deviceQuery), that all give various kinds of information about P2P (peer access) capabilities of your system.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I try to run simpleP2P test and it shows 2 GPU can't p2p access each other. Do you have any idea why it is not enabled in my machine? Following is my environment info. Thank you.

ubuntu 14.04, Tesla K80, driver version: 352.39.

Comment: It depends on your system, i.e. the motherboard, and the system BIOS.  Take a look at the answer provided by Hopobcn.  If you have these GPUs installed in a 2-socket motherboard as suggested there, then some GPUs will not be able to communicate directly (p2p) with other GPUs.  But it's impossible to give an exact answer without know which specific motherboard you have, and which sockets the GPUs are plugged into.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I bet that you have some multi-socket configuration like this one:

[image: Two K80 from different PCIe root complex]

were each K80 is not sharing the same PCIe root complex.
Then, peer-to-peer accesses from GPU0 to GPU1 are allowed, but from GPU0 to GPU2/GPU3 are not.

Tensorflow should be able to detect this kind of system and perform manual copies between GPUs.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, TensorFlow should work on a Tesla K80 GPU (although it is not one of the [officially tested devices](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1266)). As Robert Crovella points out in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37550136/does-tensorflow-support-tesla-k80#comment62588856_37550136), those warning messages merely state that your system isn't configured for peer-to-peer access between the various GPU devices, but you should still be able to run TensorFlow on them.